# How to stop Text overlapping the Icon when Text is longer in a Row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Hi apologies the title is not so clear.

I have a `Row` with a `Text` and `Icon`. Row has `verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween`

If the text in the row is longer the Icon is not visible.

how can I resolve this please

```
    Row(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    Text(
            text = title,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
            color = Color.White
    )
    Icon(
            modifier = Modifier
                    .size(24.dp),
            contentDescription = null,
            imageVector = icon,
            tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,

    )
}
```

This is a preview if text is small and text is longer where the arrow is not visible.

How can I ensure Icon is visible when the text is long please

Thanks
R

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the [`weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)) Modifier:

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
    text = title,
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
    color = Color.White
)
```

You then can remove the `horizontalArrangement` Modifier from your `Row`.

Composables with the `weight` Modifier will be measured **after** all sibling Composables without that Modifier. The remaining space is then distributed between the Composables with the `weight` Modifier. If only one Composable has the `weight` Modifier, all remaining space will be filled by that Composable.

Comment: Hello @Benjy thank you that works, also how can I add margin or padding to Icon, so that there is always a space between text and the icon please?
I tried adding padding to icon and it made the icon smaller

Comment: adding padding to the text works thank you