# Number picker issue in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a UI component in my Android app called HeightPicker, which allows users to select their height using either centimeters ('cm') or feet ('ft').
The problem arises when users switch between the 'cm' and 'ft' units: the selected height value changes unexpectedly.
Specifically, if a user selects a height in centimeters, switches to feet, and then returns to centimeters, the previously selected height value increments by 1.

Reproduce:
Launch the app and navigate to the screen containing the height picker.
Initially, the height is displayed in centimeters with a default value of 185.
Click on the 'ft' button to switch to feet.
Select a height in feet, then switch back to centimeters.
Notice that the previously selected height in centimeters has increased by 1.

Expected Behavior:
When switching between 'cm' and 'ft', the selected height value should remain unchanged.
For example, if a user selects 186 cm, switches to feet, and then returns to centimeters, the height should still be 186 cm, not 187 cm. . I have added a link to my drive so you can see a demo video of this problem [Demo Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17nszzhc6olqJck_1It1OGwk-L2OdWS9v/view)

What i have Tried:
Attempted to use boolean flags and string identifiers ('cm' and 'ft') to track the selected unit and handle the value accordingly.
Tried storing data using mutable state with ViewModel, but the issue persists.
Relevant Code Snippets:

Provided code snippets for HeightPicker, UserModel, DigitPicker, and ListItemPicker.
Mentioned the implementation of buttons for selecting 'cm' and 'ft', as well as the logic for updating the selected height value.

**UserScreen**

```
    @Composable
    fun HeightPicker() {
    var heightType by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val range = if (heightType) 50..300 else 2..12
    val text = if (heightType) "cm" else "ft"
    var pickerValue by remember { mutableStateOf(if (heightType) 185 else 5) }

    Column {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.sdp)) {
            // Button for "cm"
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier,
                colors = if (heightType) ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = AppColor) else ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    containerColor = LightestAppColor
                ),
                onClick = { heightType = true }
            ) {
                SimpleTextComponent(
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    text = "cm",
                    textColor = if (heightType) Color.White else AppColor,
                    textSize = 12.ssp,
                    fontFamily = TitleTextFont.fontFamily
                )
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(20.sdp))

            // Button for "ft"
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier,
                colors = if (!heightType) ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = AppColor) else       ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    containerColor = LightestAppColor
                ),
                onClick = {
                    heightType = false

                }
            ) {
                SimpleTextComponent(
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    text = "ft",
                    textColor = if (!heightType) Color.White else AppColor,
                    textSize = 12.ssp,
                    fontFamily = TitleTextFont.fontFamily
                )
            }
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                .padding(bottom = 120.sdp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {

            DigitPicker(
                modifier = Modifier.width(100.sdp),
                value = pickerValue,
                range = range,
                onValueChange = {
                    pickerValue = it
                    model.height = it
                    model.heightType = text},
            )
            SimpleTextComponent(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd),
                text = text,
                fontFamily = TitleTextFont.fontFamily,
                textSize = 12.ssp
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**UserModel**

```
    data class UserModel(

    var gender : String = "",
    var sedentary : String = "",
    var age : Int = 18,
    var height : Int = 185,
    var heightType : String = "cm",
    var weight : Int = 76,
    var weightType : String = "kg",
    var step : Int = 6000,
)
```

**Digit Picker**

```
    @Composable
    fun DigitPicker(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    label: (Int) -> String = {
        it.toString()
    },
    value: Int,
    range: Iterable<Int>,
    onValueChange: (Int) -> Unit,
    dividersColor: Color = AppColor,
    textStyle: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
) {
    ListItemPicker(
        modifier = modifier,
        label = label,
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        dividersColor = dividersColor,
        list = range.toList(),
        textStyle = textStyle,
    )
}
```

**ListItemPicker**

```
    private fun <T> getItemIndexForOffset(
    range: List<T>,
    value: T,
    offset: Float,
    halfNumbersColumnHeightPx: Float
    ): Int {
    val indexOf = range.indexOf(value) - (offset / halfNumbersColumnHeightPx).toInt()
    return maxOf(0, minOf(indexOf, range.count() - 1))
    }

    @Composable
    fun <T> ListItemPicker(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    label: (T) -> String = { it.toString() },
    value: T,
    onValueChange: (T) -> Unit,
    dividersColor: Color = AppColor,
    list: List<T>,
    textStyle: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    dividerHeight: Dp = 2.dp
    ) {
    val minimumAlpha = 0.3f
    val verticalMargin = 15.dp
    val numbersColumnHeight = 150.dp
    val halfNumbersColumnHeight = numbersColumnHeight / 2
    val halfNumbersColumnHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { halfNumbersColumnHeight.toPx() }

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val animatedOffset = remember { Animatable(0f) }
        .apply {
            val index = list.indexOf(value)
            val offsetRange = remember(value, list) {
                -((list.count() - 1) - index) * halfNumbersColumnHeightPx to
                        index * halfNumbersColumnHeightPx
            }
            updateBounds(offsetRange.first, offsetRange.second)
        }

    val coercedAnimatedOffset = animatedOffset.value % halfNumbersColumnHeightPx

    val indexOfElement =
        getItemIndexForOffset(list, value, animatedOffset.value, halfNumbersColumnHeightPx)

    var dividersWidth by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier
            .draggable(
                orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                state = rememberDraggableState { deltaY ->
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        animatedOffset.snapTo(animatedOffset.value + deltaY)
                    }
                },
                onDragStopped = { velocity ->
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        val endValue = animatedOffset.fling(
                            initialVelocity = velocity,
                            animationSpec = exponentialDecay(frictionMultiplier = 4f), 
                            adjustTarget = { target ->
                                val coercedTarget = target % halfNumbersColumnHeightPx
                                val coercedAnchors =
                                    listOf(
                                        -halfNumbersColumnHeightPx,
                                        0f,
                                        halfNumbersColumnHeightPx
                                    )
                                val coercedPoint =
                                    coercedAnchors.minByOrNull { abs(it - coercedTarget) }!!
                                val base =
                                    halfNumbersColumnHeightPx * (target /  halfNumbersColumnHeightPx).toInt()
                                coercedPoint + base
                            }
                        ).endState.value

                        val result = list.elementAt(
                            getItemIndexForOffset(list, value, endValue, halfNumbersColumnHeightPx)
                        )
                        onValueChange(result)
                        animatedOffset.snapTo(0f)
                    }
                }
            )
            .padding(vertical = numbersColumnHeight / 3 + verticalMargin * 2),
        content = {
            Box(
                modifier
                    .height(dividerHeight)
                    .background(color = dividersColor)
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(vertical = verticalMargin, horizontal = 20.dp)
                    .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = coercedAnimatedOffset.roundToInt()) }
            ) {
                val baseLabelModifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                ProvideTextStyle(textStyle) {
                    if (indexOfElement > 0)
                        Label(
                            text = label(list.elementAt(indexOfElement - 1)),
                            modifier = baseLabelModifier
                                .offset(y = -halfNumbersColumnHeight)
                                .alpha(
                                    maxOf(
                                        minimumAlpha,
                                        coercedAnimatedOffset / halfNumbersColumnHeightPx
                                    )
                                )
                        )
                    Label(
                        text = label(list.elementAt(indexOfElement)),
                        modifier = baseLabelModifier
                            .alpha(
                                (maxOf(
                                    minimumAlpha,
                                    1 - abs(coercedAnimatedOffset) / halfNumbersColumnHeightPx
                                ))
                            )
                    )
                    if (indexOfElement < list.count() - 1)
                        Label(
                            text = label(list.elementAt(indexOfElement + 1)),
                            modifier = baseLabelModifier
                                .offset(y = halfNumbersColumnHeight)
                                .alpha(
                                    maxOf(
                                        minimumAlpha,
                                        -coercedAnimatedOffset / halfNumbersColumnHeightPx
                                    )
                                )
                        )
                }
            }
            Box(
                modifier
                    .height(dividerHeight)
                    .background(color = dividersColor)
            )
        }
     ) { measurables, constraints ->
        // Don't constrain child views further, measure them with given constraints
        // List of measured children
        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
            // Measure each children
            measurable.measure(constraints)
        }

        dividersWidth = placeables
            .drop(1)
            .first()
            .width
            .toDp()

        // Set the size of the layout as big as it can
        layout(dividersWidth.toPx().toInt(), placeables
            .sumOf {
                it.height
            }
        ) {
            // Track the y co-ord we have placed children up to
            var yPosition = 0

            // Place children in the parent layout
            placeables.forEach {
                // Position item on the screen
                it.placeRelative(x = 0, y = yPosition)

                // Record the y co-ord placed up to
                yPosition += it.height
            }
        }
    }
}


    @Composable
    private fun Label(text: String, modifier: Modifier) {
    Text(
        modifier = modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(onLongPress = {
                // FIXME: Empty to disable text selection
            })
        },
        text = text,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontSize = 24.ssp,
        fontFamily = TitleTextFont.fontFamily,
        color = AppColor
        )
    }

    private suspend fun Animatable<Float, AnimationVector1D>.fling(
    initialVelocity: Float,
    animationSpec: DecayAnimationSpec<Float>,
    adjustTarget: ((Float) -> Float)?,
    block: (Animatable<Float, AnimationVector1D>.() -> Unit)? = null,
    ): AnimationResult<Float, AnimationVector1D> {
    val targetValue = animationSpec.calculateTargetValue(value, initialVelocity)
    val adjustedTarget = adjustTarget?.invoke(targetValue)
    return if (adjustedTarget != null) {
        animateTo(
            targetValue = adjustedTarget,
            initialVelocity = initialVelocity,
            block = block
        )
    } else {
        animateDecay(
            initialVelocity = initialVelocity,
            animationSpec = animationSpec,
            block = block,
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the logic behind this line:

```
var pickerValue by remember { mutableStateOf(if (heightType) 185 else 5) }
```

The `if` statement within the `mutableStateOf()` will be executed **exactly once** at the first composition. Afterwards, the current value will be `remember`ed across recompositions. 
 So when you change the `heightType`, `pickerValue` will remain the same. Only the `range` and `text` will update, as you didn't use `remember` for these.

I can't exactly explain the strange behavior you are observing, but I would guess what is happening is

- `heightType` is set to cm and the `pickerValue` is set to 185 initially
- `heightType` is set to inch, but the `pickerValue` remains at 185
- as 185 is out of the allowed `range`, the value will be coerced.

If you want the previous values to be restored after you switch from cm to inch and then back to cm, you will need two state variables:

```
var cmPickerValue by remember { mutableStateOf(185) }
var inchPickerValue by remember { mutableStateOf(5) }

//...

DigitPicker(
    modifier = Modifier.width(100.sdp),
    value = if (heightType) cmPickerValue else inchPickerValue,
    range = range,
    onValueChange = {
        if (heightType) {
            cmPickerValue = it
        } else {
            inchPickerValue = it
        }
        model.height = it
        model.heightType = text
    },
)
```

Alternatively, you can just call the `DigitPicker` Composable twice, once for cm and once for inch:

```
if (heightType) {
    DigitPicker(
        // use cmPickerValue in here
    )
} else {
    DigitPicker(
        // use inchPickerValue in here
    )
}
```

Please report back if that works or at least improves the current implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, I have added `model.height = cmPickerValue` and `model.heightType = text`, so that if the user returns back from 'ft' and doesn't change the value in cm, the data in cm will be set in data class.

```
if (heightType) {
    model.height = cmPickerValue
    model.heightType = text

    DigitPicker(
        // ...
    )
} else {
    model.height = ftPickerValue
    model.heightType = text

    DigitPicker(
        // ...
    )
}
```